# Make appear text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, text

I'm trying to make appear text in Javascript.

That's my code :

HTML :

```
<div id="t1">Ecologie</div>
<div id="t2">Planète</div>
<div id="t3">BIO</div>
<div id="t4">Responsable</div>
<div id="t5">Changement</div>
<div id="t6">Durable</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var mytimeout = setTimeout(DisplayElem(), 2000)
</script>
```

CSS :

```
    #t1
{
    position: absolute;
    color: green;
    font-size: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 13%;
    display: none;
}

#t2
{
    position: absolute;
    color: green;
    font-size: 60px;
    top: 40%;
    left: 70%;
    display: none;
}
```

and Javascript :

```
function Display (elem) {
    elem.style.display = block;
}

var compteur = 0;
function DisplayElem()
{
    compteur += 1;
    var id = 't' + compteur;
    elem = document.getElementById(id);
    Display(elem);
    mytimeout = setTimeout(DisplayElem(), 2000)
    if(compteur == 6)
    {
        window.clearTimeout(mytimeout);
    }
}
```

I got this error : Uncaught ReferenceError: block is not defined 
on my line :`elem.style.display = block;`

When i open my page i want all of my div invisible. But after a few second i would like to have on who appear, and the next one, and the next one...

Thank you

Comment: change it to elem.style.display = 'block'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your complete working code:

```
var compteur = 1;
function Display (elem) {
    elem.style.display = 'block';
}

function DisplayElem()
{
    var id = 't' + compteur;
    elem = document.getElementById(id);
    Display(elem);
    compteur += 1;
    if (compteur <= 6) 
        setTimeout(DisplayElem, 2000);   
}

DisplayElem();
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/eyyghgqu/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the delimiters around the string `block`:

```
function Display (elem) {
  elem.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Side note: Instead of setting the timeout the last time and then removing it, just skip setting it:

```
if (compteur < 6) {
  mytimeout = setTimeout(DisplayElem(), 2000)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now i got an other error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null  at the same line

Comment: @Quentin: That means that your `getElementById` call doesn't return an element, i.e. the element that you are looking for doesn't exist. That's because you are increasing the number before using it to create the id, so it will be looking for `t2` through `t7` instead of `t1` through `t6`.